# Build URL from output

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I am querying an API and trying to build the URL for the next query and I am pretty lost. I am getting the output I am looking for with my first command and the output looks like this:

```
8498fdsfh9238yt8hfsjhf238
38fhj38gjkdf983hgkdhg939g
j93g930jg92jy0odi03igo3t9
```

I have about 250 of these results. I need to append them to the end of a URL for my next query, so my URL needs to look like

```
https://api.example.com/ids=8498fdsfh9238yt8hfsjhf238&ids=38fhj38gjkdf983hgkdhg939g&ids=j93g930jg92jy0odi03igo3t9
```

I am really at a loss as to how to do this and anything that can point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you want the newly-generated URLs to appear? Do you want to write them to a file, or is there a command in your shell script that immediately uses the URLs?

Comment: Shouldn't the query string start with a `?`?

Comment: It does, I omitted some things for the sake of simplicity but URL string is really something like https://api.example.com/v1?ids-blah&ids=hlah

Comment: @AdminBee ideally I think I want to pipe it to something like curl

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ line=(line?line"&":"") "ids="$0 }
END{ print "https://api.example.com/"line }' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with plain shell:

```
p=
for i in aa bb cc; do
  p="$p${p:+&}ids=$i"
done
url="https://api.example.com/?$p"
```

Of course you can also write that on a single line. This builds the parameters in `$p` and adds a separator `&` when `$p` is not empty.

If your parameters are in a file `infile`, you can get them with command substitution.

```
p=
for i in $(cat infile); do
  p="$p${p:+&}ids=$i"
done
url="https://api.example.com/?$p"
```